# Update an array into filter a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Having a array values of the below need to convert another form of array using  typescript or javascript.

```
arrayList = {
['p1', 'm1', 0], 
['p1', 'm2', 2], 
['p1', 'm3', 3], 
['p2', 'm2', 3], 
['p2', 'm3', 5], 
['p3', 'm1', 3],
['p3', 'm2', 4]}
```

new array need to check with first element of array

```
array2 = { [ panel: 'p1', content: {['m1',0], ['m2', 2], ['m3', 3]}],
[ panel: 'p2', content: {['m2', 3], ['m3', 5]}],
[ panel: 'p3', content: {['m1', 3], ['m2', 4]}]  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `arrayList` and `array2` both are  not in valid format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment,both `arrayList` and `array2` are not in valid json format.

If changed them to valid json format such as below

```
let arrayList = [
['p1', 'm1', 0], 
['p1', 'm2', 2], 
['p1', 'm3', 3], 
['p2', 'm2', 3], 
['p2', 'm3', 5], 
['p3', 'm1', 3],
['p3', 'm2', 4]
]

array2 = { [ panel: 'p1', content: [['m1',0], ['m2', 2], ['m3', 3]]],
[ panel: 'p2', content: [['m2', 3], ['m3', 5]]],
[ panel: 'p3', content: [['m1', 3], ['m2', 4]]]  }
```

then you can use below code to do it

```js
let arrayList = [
['p1', 'm1', 0], 
['p1', 'm2', 2], 
['p1', 'm3', 3], 
['p2', 'm2', 3], 
['p2', 'm3', 5], 
['p3', 'm1', 3],
['p3', 'm2', 4]
]

let result = arrayList.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let obj = a.find(i => i.panel == c[0])
  if(obj){
    obj.content.push(c.slice(1))
   }else{
    obj ={'panel':c[0],'content':[c.slice(1)]}
    a.push(obj)
   }
  return a
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayList = [
['p1', 'm1', 0], 
['p1', 'm2', 2], 
['p1', 'm3', 3], 
['p2', 'm2', 3], 
['p2', 'm3', 5], 
['p3', 'm1', 3],
['p3', 'm2', 4]
]

const result = [];
arrayList.forEach(e =>{
  let item  = result.find(r=>r.panel === e[0]);
  if(item){
    item.content.push([e[1],e[2]]);
  }else {
    result.push({panel:e[0], content:[e[1], e[2]]})
  }
})
    
console.log(result)
```